# Tapping on a tabBar item should always open the first view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application with a tab bar navigation (5 buttons). Is it possible to always open the first controller of the navigation when tapping on one of the 5 tab bar buttons? For example, button1 opens VC1 (with navigation controller), which can open VC2, which can open VC3, etc. And if I am on VC3, then click on another tab bar button (let's say button2), then again click on button1, I want it to open VC1, not VC3 where I left it.

I tried with this, but for some reason it's not working like I expect:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    viewController.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: So, to make sure that I understood your case: you want to tap a tab button (let's say the third one) and it has to navigates you to the another tab (let's say the first one) and pop to its root, correct?

Comment: @AhmadF No, just when tapping on one of the tab bar buttons, it has to open the root controller of the selected tab (the first controller of its navigation).

Comment: Well, so I believe that it is the default behavior when it taps it two times (first tap for landing on the tab and the second one is for popping to the root view); You want to achieve it by only tapping one time, correct?

Comment: @AhmadF Correct, just by one tap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this functionality, I write the code in `didSelect` method of `tabBarDelegate`.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
            let rootView = self.viewControllers![self.selectedIndex] as! UINavigationController
            rootView.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this behavior is the *default* one when the user taps 2 times on the tab button (the first tap for landing to the tab and the second one for popping to the root). I would suggest to not edit this behavior because it relates to the user experience...

However, if you are aiming to achieve it (popping to the root by just 1 tap), implementing the [`tabBarController(_:didSelect:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller) as:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
  navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

should be enough, which means that your code snippet should work! Nevertheless the issue seems to be that the method is *not* even get called, therefore make sure that the view controller does conforms to the  [`UITabBarControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate), and implement:

```
tabBarController?.delegate = self
```

Adding it into the `viewDidLoad()` method should be ok.